# Luminis/Liferay portlet deployment errors

Tags: tomcat, liferay, portlet

This is my first time developing portlets with a luminis/liferay enviorment I have been trying to deploy my portlet but still getting all sorts of errors not quite sure how to fix these

```
2013-06-25 10:14:59,542 INFO  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Undeploying context [/WebApplication6]
2013-06-25 10:14:59,636 WARN  [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig Error while removing context [/WebApplication6]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.destroy(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:3670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4354)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:893)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1007)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1570)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1579)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `/WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.xml` file, the error is related to that. It complains about `xml` header, something can be there.

The most important error message is this: `The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed`. So. check the given target, maybe you misspelled something there.

Sometimes some editors save the UTF-8 Byte-Order-Mark (BOM) at the beginning of the file. Open that file ina pure text editor and check the content of the file.

Comment: Ok yea it was a dumb mistake on my part there was an extra line of code that did not belong but after fixing that i now get the error above

Comment: The error message above doesn't say too much, find some preceding exceptions.